Applying a KQL query to the transform_kql parameter through terraform
I have been asked to use terraform to create a Data Collection Rule that includes a Data source for a custom table, requiring a KQL query (transformKql) to properly format the incoming data. In summary, I cannot figure out how to code the KQL query. Here is the KQL Query that works if entered directly into the Azure Portal:
source | extend d=todynamic(RawData) | extend TimeCreated = extract(@"\d*[-]\d*[-]\d*\s\d*[:]\d*[:]\d*[.]\d*",0,RawData) | extend AppPriority = tostring(split(d,"-",3)) | extend ReqId = tostring(split(d,"-",4)) | extend Prog = tostring(split(d,"-",5)) | extend Msg = tostring(split(d,"-",6))
Here's the same string with the escape characters. This is how the string appears in the tf file:
source | extend d=todynamic(RawData) | extend TimeCreated = extract(@\"\\d*[-]\\d*[-]\\d*\\s\\d*[:]\\d*[:]\\d*[.]\\d*\",0,RawData) | extend AppPriority = tostring(split(d,\"-\",3)) | extend ReqId = tostring(split(d,\"-\",4)) | extend Prog = tostring(split(d,\"-\",5)) | extend Msg = tostring(split(d,\"-\",6))

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.
I keep getting the following error:
azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule.dcr_name: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating Data Collection Rule (Subscription: "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"
│ Resource Group Name: "rg_name"
│ Data Collection Rule Name: "dcr-name"): datacollectionrules.DataCollectionRulesClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidPayload" Message="Data collection rule is invalid" Details=[{"code":"InvalidTransformQuery","message":"Error occurred while compiling query in query: SemanticError:0x00000006 at 1:30 : Undefined symbol: RawData","target":"properties.dataFlows[0]"}]

I've also tried using the Heredoc formatting without success.

Correct me if wrong, are you trying the same query approach with terraform? @Sean Brinker

Yes. I can apply the KQL query in the Azure Portal. I cannot apply the query, in any form, through a terraform plan and terraform apply. The plan succeeds, the apply fails.

Have you tried with any simple form of query? @Sean Brinker

I have not. I am not an expert at KQL but I'll try breaking it into pieces and see if I get a different result. Thanks!

I ran another 'terraform apply' using a value of
"source | extend d=todynamic(RawData)"
for the transform_kql argument. Getting the same "InvalidPayload: Data collection rule is invalid" even though all characters that need to be escaped have been removed. So, I still have an issue just not the one I thought.

Ok will check with this query once. @Sean Brinker

The query "source | project TimeGenerated = Time, Computer, Message = AdditionalContext" is working for me. Have you tried with this? @Sean Brinker

I found out that the stream declaration had not been updated in the terraform code after figuring out a working transform_kql. It was missing a column that had been added manually during troubleshooting. Thanks for responses. They got me out of the tunnel vision I had going.

After considering different scenarios of KQL query, I found that the issue with the todynamic() function used in the source query. If I removed that specific function, it worked in all the scenarios as shown below.
If RawData is not a proper JSON or a compatible dynamic type, then converting it to dynamic might cause a conflict. So, check the type of the data does RawData has and then try the conversion from one type to another.
Run source | project typeof(RawData) in KQL log analytics workspace to retrieve the type of the content and then apply the type conversion in terraform.
By referring to the sample template azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule and also  sample data collection rules from MSDoc, I have given the below scenarios of queries as I mentioned above and worked as expected according to their respective type conversions.
1.
resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "example" {
  name                        = "jahflampul23"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  data_collection_endpoint_id = azurerm_monitor_data_collection_endpoint.example.id

  destinations {
    log_analytics {
      workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
      name                  = "example-destination-log"
    }

    event_hub {
      event_hub_id = azurerm_eventhub.example.id
      name         = "example-destination-eventhub"
    }

    storage_blob {
      storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
      container_name     = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
      name               = "example-destination-storage"
    }

    azure_monitor_metrics {
      name = "example-destination-metrics"
    }
  }
  data_flow {
    streams      = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
    destinations = ["example-destination-metrics"]
  }

  data_flow {
    streams      = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics", "Microsoft-Syslog", "Microsoft-Perf"]
    destinations = ["example-destination-log"]
  }

  data_flow {
    streams       = ["Custom-MyTableRawData"]
    destinations  = ["example-destination-log"]
    output_stream = "Microsoft-Syslog"
    transform_kql = "source | extend data = RawData"
  }

  data_sources {
    syslog {
      facility_names = ["*"]
      log_levels     = ["*"]
      name           = "example-datasource-syslog"
      streams        = ["Microsoft-Syslog"]
    }

    iis_log {
      streams         = ["Microsoft-W3CIISLog"]
      name            = "example-datasource-iis"
      log_directories = ["C:\\Logs\\W3SVC1"]
    }

    log_file {
      name          = "example-datasource-logfile"
      format        = "text"
      streams       = ["Custom-MyTableRawData"]
      file_patterns = ["C:\\JavaLogs\\*.log"]
      settings {
        text {
          record_start_timestamp_format = "ISO 8601"
        }
      }
    }

    performance_counter {
      streams                       = ["Microsoft-Perf", "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 60
      counter_specifiers            = ["Processor(*)\\% Processor Time"]
      name                          = "example-datasource-perfcounter"
    }

    windows_event_log {
      streams        = ["Microsoft-WindowsEvent"]
      x_path_queries = ["*![System/Level=1]"]
      name           = "example-datasource-wineventlog"
    }

    extension {
      streams            = ["Microsoft-WindowsEvent"]
      input_data_sources = ["example-datasource-wineventlog"]
      extension_name     = "example-extension-name"
      extension_json = jsonencode({
        a = 1
        b = "hello"
      })
      name = "example-datasource-extension"
    }
  }
  stream_declaration {
    stream_name = "Custom-MyTableRawData"
    column {
      name = "TimeGenerated"
      type = "datetime"
    }
    column {
      name = "RawData"
      type = "string"
    }
    column {
      name = "Properties"
      type = "dynamic"
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_log_analytics_solution.example
  ]
}


2.
 data_flow {
  streams       = ["Custom-MyTableRawData"]
  destinations  = ["example-destination-log"]
  output_stream = "Microsoft-Syslog"
  transform_kql = "source | extend data = tostring(AdditionalContext) | project TimeGenerated = Time, computer"
}



Thanks for the thorough explanation. Ultimately, the issue was not the string in the transform_kql argument. Instead it was the stream declaration. It was not updated to reflect the change to the column names. I feel pretty dumb for not checking the rest of the Data Collection Rule before getting wrapped around the axle of escape sequences. Thanks again for the response!

Strictly speaking, this answer did not solve the issue but Jahnavi's responses were primarily responsible for refocusing my troubleshooting which ultimately led me to the stream declaration.
